# Objective Sharpie not linking frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to integrate Bluetherm device with my Xamarin project. I have library file which is received from Bluetherm, for which I need to create binding files (Xamarin.ios specific) through Visual Studio. But getting lots of errors. I have resolved most of the errors. But still struggling with following error.

> The type or namespace name '_RuneLocale' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>   (BluethermBinding) ApiDefinitions.cs(3,3): Error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>   (BluethermBinding)

Tried to added CoreFoundation Framework and foundation framework of native iOS but no any luck. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Those types are part of the iOS SDK. Did you use the parameter "-scope ." when working with Objective Sharpie?

Comment: nope. not used.

Comment: Oh. Just try the sharpie command again with additional "-scope ." to limit the bindings to your lib only